# Can you run earth ground thru conduit into home?

Tags: grounding

I have a detached garage that I am running coax and cat6 to. Running pvc conduit underground from house to garage. My question is when the conduit comes up out of the ground and into a 1 gang pvc box before continuing upwards to penetrate into a/v enclosure.

Can i use 2nd open inlet on the bottom of the 1 gang box for earth ground to connect to coax ground block inside the 1 gang box. And then the ground continue up and into the garge a/v box to ground the box inside?

Comment: What makes you think you can't do this? Perhaps I'm not understanding the question, but this doesn't seem to have anything to do with the conduit...

Comment: No. But not for why you think. If the coax is grounded at the house, that should be its single ground point, it should not be re-grounded at the garage.  Same rule for the cat6 if it’s STP, only one end gets the ground.

Comment: Does this garage have its own grounding electrode system?

Answer (score 1):

All A/V equipment should be grounded at the main disconnect via a intersystem bonding terminal block attached usually to the grounding electrode wire right below the main disconnect.

Unless your detached garage has it's own main disconnect, which you'd know what to do by the above paragraph, then you are really only bonding the coax at that stage which is probably not hurting anything unless the detached garage is not grounded/bonded properly itself.

**Intersystem Bonding Terminal**

[image]